# Validating a custom expression with ER

Tags: regex, entity-relationship

i am trying to validate a custom expression. This expression contains the follow conditions:

- Number position;
- Type operation;
- Expression;
- Alias (optional);
- Comment (optional);

The conditions are separated by "|" pipe. So, four pipes is the limit.

So, to be a valid expression:

0|S|write(&var1)|alias1|my coment   - OK
0|K|write(&var1)|alias1|my coment   - FAIL
1|I|read(&var2)|alias2|         - OK
1|S|read(&var1)||           - OK
2|N|if(&var1 == &var2);read(&var3)||    - OK
3|S|||                  - FAIL
3|I|write(&var1)|alias 3|       - FAIL
3|N|write(&var1)|alias1|my coment|  - FAIL

I am using this ER to validate:

^(\d{1,10})\|(S|M|I|N)\|(.+?)\|([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?\|(.+)?

But i can not validate the expression that ends with pipe. Because, in a comment can have any caracter except a pipe...

Some idea??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `[^|]` instead of `(.+)?` at the end of your regex:

```
^(\d{1,10})\|(S|M|I|N)\|[^|]+\|([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\|([^|]*)$
```

As a side note: for every sub-expression *subexpr* the following regexes are equivalent:

```
((subexpr)+)?
```

and

```
(subexpr)*
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's any character except the pipe, you can modify the regex so to add this rule at the end:

```
^(\d{1,10})\|(S|M|I|N)\|(.+?)\|([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?\|([^\|]+)?$
```